# why fmt.Fscan can't read lowcase letter to a byte value?

Tags: go

code like this :

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader("a" +
        "2" +
        "3"))
    var a byte
    fmt.Fscan(reader, &a)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

it will output `0`

but if I change input to this :

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader("1" +
        "2" +
        "3"))
    var a byte
    fmt.Fscan(reader, &a)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

output is:
[image]

I change input from `a\n2\n3` to `1\n2\n3`.  caused `a` can't scan into a value.

I don't konw why, who can explain it to me? thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 4):

`fmt.Fscan` examines the types of the input arguments to drive its parsing behavior. In this case, the only input argument is of type `byte`, which is a built-in type alias of `uint8` ([link](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20/src/builtin/builtin.go#88)), which causes `fmt.Fscan` to try to parse an unsigned number out of the input `io.Reader` ([link](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20/src/fmt/scan.go#988)). `123` can successfully be parsed as an unsigned number whereas `a23` cannot. `fmt.Fscan` does have return values of the number of items successfully scanned and an error, which you're discarding. If you print the error out, that'll make it easier to spot the problem.

If your goal is to read some input byte by byte, you can use the `Read` off of the `io.Reader` directly.